# Divide in Django Templates

Tags: django, django-templates

I have django template in which I want to divide a td component by another, How cain I do that ?

```
  {% for i in query %}
        <tr>


            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.owner }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.pk }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.flow }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.kit.components_per_kit }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.quantity }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.is_allocated }}</td>
            <td class="align-middle">{{ i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.created_on }}</td>

       </tr>
        {% endfor %}
```

I want to do something like this:

```
    <td class="align-middle">{{ divide i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.quantity i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.kit.components_per_kit }}</td>
```

But when I do this I get the following error:

> Invalid block tag on line 42: 'divide', expected 'empty' or 'endfor'.
>   Did you forget to register or load this tag?

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please don't. Business logic should be handled in the *view*. Not in the *template*. The template is used for *rendering* logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used a custom_tag for this:

custom_tag.py

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b


@register.simple_tag
def divide(a, b):
    return int(a / b)
```

Call this in the template

**Html**

```
{% load custom_tags %}

{% for i in query %}
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">{% divide i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.quantity i.pending_docket_list.sales_order.kit.components_per_kit %}</td>
```